# Change excel default cursor to arrow pointer

Tags: vba, excel-2013

I am developing a application on excel 2013 using vba, I want the user of application always see arrow pointer instead of excel default cursor (plus [+] looking cursor).
I know there is a following method:

```
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
```

But this is not working for me, is there any API function for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the normal arrow cursor, use:

```
Application.Cursor = xlNorthwestArrow
```

The [`+`] cursor *is* the default, so you have to call the arrow cursor specifically.